# How to get first n numbers from float

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table A with two columns `id(int)` and `f_value(float)`. Now I'd like to select all rows where `f_value` starts from '123'. So for the following table:

```
id | f_value
------------
1  | 12
2  | 123
3  | 1234
```

I'd like to get the second and third row. I tried to use LEFT with cast but that was a disaster. For the following query:

```
select f_value, str(f_value) as_string, LEFT(str(f_value), 2) left_2,
       LEFT(floor(f_value), 5) flor_5, LEFT('abcdef', 5) test
   from A
```

I got:

```
f_value  | as_string | left_2 | flor_5 | test
------------------------------------------------
40456510 | 40456510  |        | 4.045  |  abcde
40454010 | 40454010  |        | 4.045  |  abcde
404020   | 404020    |        | 40402  |  abcde
40452080 | 40452080  |        | 4.045  |  abcde
101020   | 101020    |        | 10102  |  abcde
404020   | 404020    |        | 40402  |  abcde
```

The question is why left works fine for 'test' but for other returns such weird results?

**EDIT:**

I made another test I now I'm even more confused. For query:

```
Declare @f as float
set @f = 40456510.

select LEFT(cast(@f as float), LEN(4045.)), LEFT(404565., LEN(4045.))
```

I got:

```
     |
------------ 
4.04 | 4045
```

Is there a default cast which causes this?
[Fiddle SQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/185b8/1)

Comment: where left(f_value, 3) = '123'

Comment: What if the value is 12.3 or .123 ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff you are probably right, so answered according to that assumption

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem was that SQL Server uses the exponential representation of floats. To resolve it you need to first convert float to BigInt and then use Left on it.

Example:

```
Select * from A where Left(Cast(float_value as BigInt), 4) = xxxx
```

Comment: That won't work across the full range of float values. It doesn't appear that that's a problem for your case though but it's worth noting for somebody else who tries this.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #TestTable(ID INT, f_value FLOAT)
INSERT INTO #TestTable
VALUES  (1,22),
        (2,123),
        (3,1234)

SELECT *
FROM #TestTable
WHERE LEFT(f_value,3)='123'

DROP TABLE #TestTable
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your query is a bit wrong. The `LEFT` part should go in the `WHERE`-Clause, not the `SELECT`-part.

Also, just use `LIKE` and you should be fine:

```
SELECT f_value, str(f_value) as_string, LEFT(str(f_value), 2) left_2,
       LEFT(floor(f_value), 5) flor_5
WHERE f_value LIKE '123%'
```

Comment: Does'n work. For my example this will return only the second row.

Comment: @orim: Are you sure you added the percent sign at the end?

Comment: Yes, and I know why. The problem is that floats are casted to varchar in a wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the `FLOAT` value  to `DECIMAL` then to `VARCHAR` using `CAST` AND use `LIKE` to select the value starting with `4045`.

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE CAST(CAST(f_value AS DECIMAL(20,12)) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) LIKE '4045%';
```

[Fiddle demo for reference](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6f1d86/30)

Comment: Does'n work. For my example this will return only the second row.

Comment: Please check the fiddle demo. There it returns the second and third rows.

Comment: @orim: I have updated the answer. Please see the attached fiddle too.

Answer (score 0):

The replace get rid of the period in the float, by multiplying by 1 any 0 in front will be removed.

```
SELECT f_value
FROM your_table
WHERE replace(f_value, '.', '') * 1 like '123%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
returns significant digits from @f (a float) as an integer
negative sign is stripped off
*/
declare @num_digits int = 3; /* needs to be positive; accuracy diminishes with larger values */
with samples(num, f) as (
    select 1, cast(123.45 as float) union
    select 2, 123456700 union
    select 3, -1.234567 union
    select 4, 0.0000001234
)
select num, f,
    case when f = 0 or @num_digits < 1 then 0 else
        floor(
            case sign(log10(abs(f)))
                when -1 then abs(f) * power(10e0,  -floor(log10(abs(f))) + @num_digits - 1)
                when  1 then abs(f) / power(10e0, ceiling(log10(abs(f))) - @num_digits)
            end
        )
    end as significant_digits
from samples
order by num;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/43228)